# Can external API content be added to Rest API in Wordpress

Tags: php, rest-api, api

Is it possible to fetch data from an external API, and put them inside of Wordpress REST API?

For example, schema would look like this

```
 $api = 'https://valorant-api.com/v1/agents';

 $json_data = file_get_contents($api);

 $response_data = json_decode($json_data);

 $user_data = $response_data->data;

 $user_data = array_slice($user_data,0,20);

 foreach($user_data as $agent) {

    $sendToRest = $agent->displayIcon);
    array_push($sendToRest,$restArray);
 }
```

This is the logic that i came up with, but i dont know if this is okay or not, but you get the point :)

Comment: the best way is to prepare corresponding data in your WP structure - some custom post type including all data and call whenever you want. Prepare synchronization between WP and external API - and grab data from WP. You will have more control over when and how is data synchronized.
Second is to prepare endpoint in your WP with parameters and call external API trough that endpoint.